# How to add columns with different levels and get their frequency in R

Tags: r

I have a few columns that contain `0`'s and `1`'s and some with just `0`. I would like to add these columns together to count the frequency of `0`'s and `1`'s for several columns at a time.

However, when I try to add these columns I get the error below.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

> Error in table(mini_data$col1) + table(mini_data$col2):
> non-conformable arrays

I know it is because there are 2 levels in `col2` and 1 level in `col1` and you can't add columns of different lengths/arrays. I would like to know if there is a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only because the `levels` are different.  We can make the `levels` same by taking the `union` of `levels` of both columns (assuming the columns are `factor`) and then do the `table`

```
lvls <- union(levels(mini_data$col1), levels(min_data$col2))
mini_data$col1 <- factor(mini_data$col1, levels = lvls)
mini_data$col2 <- factor(mini_data$col2, levels = lvls)
```

Now we do the `table`

```
table(mini_data$col1) + table(mini_data$col2)
```